# Gitlab-runner, docker:20.10.2-dind shows error, Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-runner

On self hosted Gitlab on GCP installed by helm, I use Gitlab-runner.

On gitlab-runner I need to use docker so using dind, but I got error

> tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

gitlab-runner deployment

```
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /bin/bash
        - /scripts/entrypoint
        env:
        - name: CI_SERVER_URL
          value: https://my-gitlab.com
        - name: CLONE_URL
        - name: RUNNER_REQUEST_CONCURRENCY
          value: "1"
        - name: RUNNER_EXECUTOR
          value: kubernetes
        - name: REGISTER_LOCKED
          value: "false"
        - name: RUNNER_TAG_LIST
        - name: KUBERNETES_IMAGE
        - name: KUBERNETES_PRIVILEGED
          value: "true" # <= set privileged true to use dind
...
```

gitlab-ci.yaml

```
services:
  - docker:20.10.4-dind

stages:
    - build

variables:
    GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"    
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

image:
    name: google/cloud-sdk:latest
before_script:
  - docker version

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo hello
```

gitlab-runner log

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ docker version
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.11
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        42e35e61f3
 Built:             Mon Jun  1 09:09:53 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

[troubleshooting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-tcpdocker2375-is-the-docker-daemon-running) says that it's because of TLS. So I set  `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''` , the way written in another [document](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/31/docker-in-docker-with-docker-19-dot-03/).

Also, this problem didn't happen when I used `docker:19.03.0-dind`. From 19.03.0-dind, TLS is automatically. So disable TLS configuration must be worked correctly.
(docker:19.3.13-dind also worked well.)

I don't know why from docker:20 this error showed up. Has anyone already tried gitlab-runner with grater than docker:20 ?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that I should follow https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-in-docker-with-tls-enabled-in-kubernetes

toml

```
runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        image = "ubuntu:20.04"
        privileged = true
      [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.empty_dir]]
        name = "docker-certs"
        mount_path = "/certs/client"
        medium = "Memory"
```

gitlab-ci.yaml

```
services:
  - docker:20.10.4-dind

stages:
    - build

variables:
    GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"    
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs" 
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"    
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
    DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
    
image:
    name: google/cloud-sdk:latest
before_script:
  - docker version

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo hello
```

Comment: For me, `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"` doesn't need to be set for it to work